# angular2 getting the whole object selected in a select box

Tags: javascript, html, angular

In the past I was able to pass out the 'object' that was used for the select options. I'd like to capture that information off a regular select, but I cannot remember how.

So When you do an *ngFor in your select option, you specify a N of N's like this

```
<option *ngFor="let thing of things" value= {{thing.name}}>
    {{thing.family}} - {{thing.name}}
</option>
```

I'm hoping I can get that 'whole' thing that was selected, by calling a function  on change.

```
<select class="form-control input-sm " 
        (change)="changeThing($event)" 
        name="thing" 
        formControlName="thing" >

    <option *ngFor="let thing of things" value= {{thing.name}}>
        {{thing.family}} - {{thing.name}}
    </option>

</select>
```

because I want to change some form options based on the 'family' of the thing, not the value that gets passed.

my function looks like this.

```
changeThing (thing) {
    console.log('thing:', thing);
    selectedFamily = ??;
}
```

The $event is probably the wrong thing to be looking at - I can get the value selected there, but I cannot find the whole "thing" that was selected.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1):

You can do that with the help of `index`

**Template Side :**

```
<select class="form-control input-sm " 
        [(ngModel)]="selectedValue"
        (change)="changeThing($event.target.value)" 
        name="thing" >
    <option *ngFor="let thing of things; let i = index;" [value]="i">
        {{thing.family}} - {{thing.name}}
    </option>
</select>
```

**Component Side :**

```
changeThing(index){
    alert(this.things[index].family +' '+this.things[index].name );
    console.log(this.things[index]);
}
```

**[WORKING DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-select-object)**

Answer (score 0):

I hope it will help

```
<option *ngFor="let thing of things" value= {{thing}}>
        {{thing.family}} - {{thing.name}}
    </option>
```

Comment: Yes Aay, that will get me the whole thing, but I want the selected value to be the name, I just want some added information so I can change other things on the page - before the form is submitted.

Answer (score 0):

You can use ngModel with ngModelChange

```
<select [(ngModel)] ="selectedType" (ngModelChange)="changeThing(selectedType)">
     <option *ngFor="let thing of things" [ngValue]="thing ">
            {{type.name}}
     </option>
</select>
```

Comment: This kind of works, the ngModel conflicts with the reactive forms method of using formControlName="thing"...but I think I can munge something together , and then I'll ask for refinements.